# Calling a class into grid

Tags: java, class, applet, awt, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a Weather applet for school but I'm having a problem calling a class to a main class.  In the end I will want 3 permanent components (Location, Temperature, Precipitation) then in image box I want to do an if statement that pics the appropriate image from the data in components.

### Layout idea

[image]

### Main Class code

```
// The "Weather" class.
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Weather extends Applet
{
//TempBar Intergers
    //int x= 
    //int y=
    //int H=    //H = Heat

    //PercipBar Intergers
    //int x2=
    //int y2=
    //int P =   //P = pericipitation

    public void init ()
    {
       GridLayout umm = new GridLayout(0,2);
       PercipBar percip = new PercipBar();
       getContentPane.addItem (percip());
    } 

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
    } 
}
```

### PercipBar Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class PercipBar extends Applet 
{
     int x2 =2;
     int y2 =2;

     int P =80;//P = percipitation will be declared in main file

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        g.drawRect (x2, y2, 100, 20);//outline of bar
        g.setColor (Color.blue);
        g.fillRect (x2+1, y2+4, P, 14 ); //indicator bar (+4 puts space beetween outline bar)
    }
}
```

Comment: *"make a Weather applet for school"*  1) Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should *stop* teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Same deal with AWT vs. Swing.  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  A `JLabel` can display an image easily, while an AWT based `Label` supports only text.

Answer (score 0):

That GUI seems well suited to being contained in a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).

- `location gui` would be put in position `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`
- `image` would be put in `BorderLayout.CENTER`
- `temp` would be put in `BorderLayout.LINE_END`
- `percip` (which is spelled `precip`) would be put in position `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`

Note that the precipitation bar should net be another applet!  It should just be a `Component`.

In order to be assigned space in the `BorderLayout`, a custom painted component will need to return a sensible preferred size.

Preferably, rather than custom paint such things, just use a `Label` to display the text.  That way, we don't need to override either the `paint` method or `getPreferredSize`.  The GUI will takes its hints from the natural size of the label.